# Laravel add custom method for all eloquent models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am looking for a way to add few custom methods which will be used in all models. I can imagine 3 ways of doing it :

1. Adding custom method to main Eloquent's Model.php class file(I want to avoid doing this as this is a core file)
2. Creating a custom model class with required custom methods, which will extend to eloquent's Model class and all the models in the project will extend to custom model class.
3. Adding a trait which will have my methods and include it inside all models

However, I want to do it more efficiently and best way possible. Is their any other way to do it?

PS I am using laravel 5.2 as its an old project.

Comment: #1 is definitely a bad approach. #2 and #3 are both good approaches. I'd use #2 if literally *all* models (including any future ones your app will ever have) need the extra functionality, and #3 if only *some* of them will.

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion and adding my experience in Laravel I would suggest you to go either with #2 or #3 approach as @ceejayoz have specified in the comments

first one is definitely a bad approach as you need to modify the core which is not at all a good practice. Second and third are both good approaches.

But, before that you need to check your requirements if literally all models (including any future ones your app will ever have) need the extra functionality, however you can use traits for all models.

If I have the choice probably I will go for traits over custom models as traits are relatively simple then custom models

Comment: don't do downvotes if you have solved your issue or doubt then post the appropriate answer so that others may get help from your question thanks :)

Comment: please accept the answer so that this question can be closed thanks :)